# Italicising part of a word?

Tags: support, comment, markdown

Is there a way to italicise part of a work? I wanted to write *un*sure, but this doesn't work because the "un" is part of the word. However, *un*-sure works. Is there a better way?

EDIT: I wanted to use it in a comment. So something which works in a comment would be useful.

Comment: Related meta.SO post: [Allow Italics Mid-Word](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62723/allow-italics-mid-word). It is marked [meta-tag:status-completed], but it is mentioned there that it does not work in comments.

Comment: All the hacks with Mathjax are gratuitously inaccessible.

Comment: Back in 2009, Atwood described the creation of "mini-Markdown" (how he calls the subset of Markdown implemented in comments here) [on his blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/testing-with-the-force.html), with a focus on when to turn asterisks into italics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MathJax is a solution, which works both in question/answer bodies and in comments. However, it gives you another font, but it might be a decent hack nevertheless.

`$un$sure`: $un$sure

Comment: \$un\textrm{sure}\$ -> $un\textrm{sure}$

Comment: That also works, but then it's more obvious that $the$ $\textrm{font has changed}$.

Comment: Ahh, good point

Comment: Also, unfortunately mathjax doesn't support that much text manipulation. So something like `$\rtextnormal{\emph{un}sure}$` doesn't work.

Comment: The solution `$un$sure` also has the disadvantage that, if you're unlucky, a line break might occur between "un" and "sure".

Comment: I accepted this one on the basis that it is the only option which works in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `<i>` HTML tag:

`<i>un</i>sure`: *un*sure

---

NB. Does not work in comments.

**Edit by dfeuer:** Even better, use `<em>un</em>sure` *un*sure, which expresses the semantic intent and should thus be better for users who use custom stylesheets, unless Markdown screws it up.

Comment: <i>un</i>sure. Does not work in comments.

Comment: Or cheating with MathJax: `$un$sure`: $un$sure

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to use it in a comment. Using `$un$sure` works, but it gives you a different font. It is a decent hack though - and you (@DanielR) should post it as answer.

Comment: @user1729 Done!

Comment: This is by far the best solution as it is by far the least likely to trip up a system like emacspeaks, which will likely voice the other proposals completely incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to separate two "words" without having visible space. There's a way to do that: a [zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space). `*un*&#8203;sure` gives *un*​sure.

Edit: unfortunately, empirically this doesn't work in comments, even if you copy-paste the ZWS rather than using an HTML entity.

To save other people trying, I've also tested `*un*$$sure` (renders all of those characters) and `*un*${}$sure` (renders the asterisks, and if you then edit the comment also renders the dollars and braces).

Comment: And just to check that it works in comments too: *un*&#8203;sure.

Comment: Ok, copy-pasting: *un*​sure.

Comment: How about *un*$$sure or *un*${}$sure?